# Azure AD B2C Session Managment for Sign Up Only flows (don't read just write session cookies)

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have 2 separate user journeys for Sign-In and Sign-Up using just local accounts in my custom policies.

For the Sign-In flow I can add `<UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />` to my sign-in page's technical profile to both persist a new session, or to skip the page if there is already a session.

However, for my Sign-Up flow, I want to persist new sessions, but I don't want to skip the sign-up screens if they already have a session. I want them to see all of the screens and restart. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: In what scenario would a user have a session and then sign up?

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT not any real legitimate ones, but maybe a user who is confused and clicks the sign up link in their email again. I guess in that scenario I want to sign them in all the way?….. or maybe a testing scenario, where the admin is signed in after creating a new account.